# Login URL using authentication information in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm working on a platform for online labs registration for my university.

### Login View [project views.py]

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib import auth

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if post.has_key('username') and post.has_key('password'):
            usr = post['username']
            pwd = post['password']
            user = auth.authenticate(username=usr, password=pwd)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                if user.get_profile().is_teacher:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/teachers/'+user.username+'/')
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/students/'+user.username+'/')
            else:
                return render_to_response('index.html', {'msg': 'You don\'t belong here.'}, context_instance = RequestContext(request)

    return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

### URLS

```
#========== PROJECT URLS ==========#

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT }),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    (r'^teachers/', include('diogenis.teachers.urls')),
    (r'^students/', include('diogenis.students.urls')),
    (r'^login/', login),
    (r'^logout/', logout),
    (r'^$', index),
)

#========== TEACHERS APP URLS ==========#

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^(?P<username>\w{0,50})/', labs),
)
```

The login view basically **checks whether the logged in user is_teacher** [UserProfile attribute via get_profile()] and redirects the user to his profile.

### Labs View [teachers app views.py]

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import *
from labs.models import *

def user_is_teacher(user):
    return user.is_authenticated() and user.get_profile().is_teacher

@user_passes_test(user_is_teacher, login_url="/login/")
def labs(request, username):
    q1 = User.objects.get(username=username)
    q2 = u'%s %s' % (q1.last_name, q1.first_name)
    q2 = Teacher.objects.get(name=q2)
    results = TeacherToLab.objects.filter(teacher=q2)

    return render_to_response('teachers/labs.html', {'results': results}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I'm using @user_passes_test decorator for checking whether the authenticated user has the permission to use this view [labs view].

The problem I'm having with the current logic is that once Django authenticates a teacher user he has access to all teachers profiles basically by typing the teachers username in the url.
**Once a teacher finds a co-worker's username he has direct access to his data.**

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't really need to post all that code... just the view would have been sufficient.

Comment: You could also make a OneToOneField link from your Teacher model to User, so that you can just do q2 = q1.teacher

Comment: I apologise, i thought i was missing something in the urls.py.
A better way to pass the username maybe, something that could prevent such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to modify the view to add an extra check:

```
@user_passes_test(user_is_teacher, login_url="/login/")
def labs(request, username):
    if username != request.user.username:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed()
    ... and so on ...
```

Comment: My first thought, thank you.
Is there a way to use a decorator instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable called 'teacher' that represents the profile of the teacher whose profile you're viewing, just do something like this early in the view:

```
if request.user.get_profile() != teacher:
  ..redirect, throw 404, whatever you fancy
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a short hint.

```
...

user = request.user
enrollment = get_object_or_404(Enrollment, id=enrollment_id)
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)

if not (enrollment.profile == profile or user.is_staff):
    raise Http404

...

enrollment.delete()
```

We used such `if` statements to determine, whether the actual user and the action he requested match. In the example above, only the `profile` who create an enrollment is allowed to delete it (or someone with `staff` priviledges).